# subquerying in hive with left outer join or where exists

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm trying to do multiple nested subqueries. First find lowercase names with role "Person", then find `session_ids` that those people have had. With that list of `session ids`, I want to filter the original query, by all results that are in those `session ids`

```
select 
U.session_id,
U.session_date,
U.email
from data.usage U
left outer join
  select 
  distinct M.session_id
  from data.usage M
  where email like '%gmail.com%'
  and data_date >= '20180101'
  and name in
    ( 
    select 
    lower(name)
    from data.users
    where role like 'Person%' 
    and isactive = TRUE
    and data_date = '20180412'
    )
on U.session_id = M.session_id
```

I'm able to get the subqueries to work on their own, and results in a list of `session_ids`, I've tried using `where session_id in (subqueries)` but that doesn't work. I've also tried doing something like `where exists`, or `left outer join`, but I haven't be able to get any of them to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After left outer join **keep alias name** for the all the query you have written to M then run the query again.

**Try to run below Query:**

```
select 
U.session_id,
U.session_date,
U.email
from data.usage U
left outer join
  (select 
  distinct M.session_id
  from data.usage M
  where email like '%gmail.com%'
  and data_date >= '20180101'
  and name in
    ( 
    select 
    lower(name)
    from data.users
    where role like 'Person%' 
    and isactive = TRUE
    and data_date = '20180412'
    ))M
on U.session_id = M.session_id
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much. Can you explain exactly why I need to keep the alias name?

Comment: One of the rule while writing sub query is **subquery must always appear within parentheses,You can embed a subquery inside another one. You can have as many level as you need.** When we keep alias name(M) then all the sub query will be treated as a table M.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the explanation. That is clearer!